# Tabu list length vs cadency

Tags: algorithm, heuristics, tabu-search

I'm trying to solve TSP problem with tabu search. I understand most foundations of this heuristic method. But I have trouble with figuring out what is the difference between cadence of some tabu move and length of tabu list. These two data structures are mentioned in most tutorials and documents available on the web. I would be grateful for some explanation about this difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
tabu_list = (attr1, cadence1), (attr2, cadence2), . . . ((attr n, cadence n)
```

Move is forbidden if a certain attribute is on the list
of prohibited moves (tabu list).

1) Tabu list length - specifies the max number of elements, that can be on tabu_list

2) Cadency - specifies the number of iterations through, which the element (attribute, cadence) is on the tabu_list